# ASP.NET [Need an event after page load (After GridView renew data) ]

Tags: asp.net

I **renew parameters of my DataSource for GridView** on Button and loads event Page_Load()
and After it (or with it) GridView renews itself.

I need to rename Header rows but **there is no event after Page Load.**

more information about details here :

```
[On Button Click] I change DataSource and Bind it (SqlDataSource1.DataBind(); ) Then sure Page gone to Refresh elements.
```

[On Page_Load] GridView is changing data, but if I can't change Headers there because it's looking like loads after this function :(

[one more Button] I can add new button with a function - rename headers and it works correct everytime

```
    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Stack overflow
    DataRow T;
    if (go)
        if (GridView2.HeaderRow.Cells.Count != 0)
            for (int i = 0; i < SQF.SQF.Permission.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                T = SQF.SQF.Permission.Rows[i];
                GridView2.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Text = (string)T["Caption1"];
                WebMsgBox.Show((string)T["Caption1"]);
            }
}
```

Trouble : I no need one more button for it, I need to rename header rows after I click button to change Data but I have no idea where I can do it.

thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you could use Gridview DataBound event, like that:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="SomeID" OnDataBound="GridVIew_OnDataBound" ... />
```

The DataBound event occurs right after the databinding process for that particular control has completed.

Answer (score 1):

After Page_Load there is an event `Page.PreRender`.
Maybe it will suit you.

EDIT.
All events of your components, such as GridView, are fired between Page.Load and Page.PreRender. Consider using `RowDataBound` and `RowUpdated` events.

Comment: Error here : if (GridView2.HeaderRow.Cells.Count != 0)
seems like there is nothing in grid yet :(

Comment: answer on EDIT , but if "All events of your components, such as GridView, are fired between Page.Load and Page.PreRender" Why I get error then and OnDataBound got no error ??